# How to avoid packages missing after upgrading Debian 10 to Debian 11?

Tags: debian, upgrade, debian-bullseye

I rarely do a server upgrade. Having said this I today upgraded Debian 10 to Debian 11 using these [instructions](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-upgrade-debian-10-to-debian-11/) which appeared pretty straightforward.

The issue was that after the upgrade some of the previously installed PHP packages were missing. Moreover, MariaDB was no longer there. I mitigated this by installing the missing PHP packages and also reinstalling the MariaDB database server again.

However, I have the feeling that something went wrong with the process which otherwise went smoothly. Any hints on how do avoid such issues in the future?

Comment: The missing packages were non-official, right? This may or may not help, but I would "apt dist-upgrade" before changing version. Also, when you upgrade check whether APT is trying to remove packages before accepting.

Comment: Thanks al lot for the info. I'd say that mariadb-server is as official as a package can get. The PHP extensions were not though. Anyhow, thanks a bunch for the tip using 'apt dist-upgrade'. Will do this next time.

Comment: There is no `apt dist-upgrade` but rather an `apt-get dist-upgade` which in turn equals the `apt full-upgrade` I used. There must be another reason for this supposedly strange behaviour.

Comment: I meant to do an `apt-get upgrade` before editing the `sources.list`. Anyway I was just giving a generic recommendation, probably not related. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. This is basically what the instructions I followed suggest to do too.